# How to get Visual Studio to ignore my XML "errors" in markdown files?

Tags: xml, visual-studio, markdown, visual-studio-2013

I have a markdown file with some documentation. To make it format in a certain way, there are a few pieces of raw HTML in the file. This apparently causes Visual Studio to try to emulate Clippy and attempt to help me make my markdown files XML compliant

[image]

As lovely as it is for Visual Studio to tell me why my markdown file isn't valid XML, I really hate having squigly red lines underneath every single piece of text in the file.

How do I get Visual Studio 2013 to stop assuming my markdown is XML/HTML?

Comment: Stop telling VS your file is XML when it isn't. Change the file name extension.

Comment: @DourHighArch the file ends in `.md`. I've also tried changing it to `.mkd` for good measure. same thing both ways

Comment: Check your Tools > Options > Text Editor. Something's telling VS .mkd files are XML.

Comment: @DourHighArch like what? I don't see anything where I could tell Visual Studio that a file other than .xml is XML. And for reference, this happened before installing any extensions. I tried installing extensions to see if it would fix it heh

Comment: Tools > Options > Text Editor > File Extension is my guess. My VS does not show the behavior you describe.

Comment: @DourHighArch that's empty on my machine. Neither me or any program has added file extensions options there. In fact, I tried manually adding `.md` there so that it opens with Source (text) Editor, and it still does the same XML auto-detect crap

Comment: What happens if you **close all** your _.md_ documents, right-click on one of them, choose _Open with..._, choose _Source Code (Text) Editor_, then _Set as Default_ and _OK_?

Comment: @AlexFilipovici no change. Still giving XML errors

Comment: Same problem here. Very annoying "feature" :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just set file's `Build Action` to `None` instead of `C# compiler` in file properties.
(And rename your file extension to '*.md' of course)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have a build action set for your markdown file. This can be changed by right-clicking the file and asking for properties.

I encountered this by asking Visual Studio to create me a class file and I later renamed it to "Readme.md" without adjusting the build action that was automatically assigned since I'd asked for a class file.